# IFRAME Set Height to 100%

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to set the height of my iframe to 100%.
But for some reason I can't do that.
I want to remove scroll so to iframe every time display like height 100%.

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<iframe src="https://example.com/" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your div need a fixed height. Have you try the style **position: fixed; left:0; right:0; top:0 bottom:0;**?

Comment: This question has neither php nor javascript in it

Comment: @Patfreeze I add but it's the same issue

Comment: You need to provide then more code because just a `div` and a `iframe` does'nt help to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Patfreeze  Pls check above, I make code to able to run, open in full screen I have same issues on my end to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. It worked for me:

```html
<html>
<body style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:fixed; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
        <iframe src="https://example.com/" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that this can work, is possible to add some margin or padding? I am implementing that in WordPress in the page I have an issue with sidebar, the page goes under sidebar.

Comment: Ajust the `top:0;` like `top:50px`. This will move the div 50px from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I am unable to test it at the moment but you can try.  **Scrolling may be either no or none I can't remember.

```
<style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0; 
                height: 100%; 
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content{
                position: absolute; 
                left: 0; 
                right: 0; 
                bottom: 0; 
                top: 0px; 
            }
</style>

<div id="content">
<iframe src="example.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="none" height="100%" width="100%" style="overflow:hidden></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jay I can only use inline CSS, Try to run my above code in full screen, you can see that for some reason cant display 100% height